# My USB modem is not mounting

Tags: usb, usb-modem

my USB modem is displaying in my computer option.

```
Unable to mount location
Can't mount file
```

here is error :

```
Error mounting /dev/sr1 at /media/istiaq/GP Internet: Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr1" "/media/istiaq/GP Internet"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: special device /dev/sr1 does not exist.
```